# How to set up disk automount in Ubuntu Server

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, raspberrypi, automount

I'm setting up a small home server consisting of a Raspberry with Ubuntu server.

Specifically, I installed

> Ubuntu 23.10 (GNU/Linux 6.5.0-1007-raspi aarch64)

I'm currently manually mounting every single drive that comes in, and as you can imagine, that's not exactly a comfortable thing to do.

I read that it is possible to enable each disk individually from the **/etc/fstab** file, but if I also connect a very common USB stick foreign to the system, someone will have to log in with administration credentials to mount the new device.

**How can I automatically mount any disk connected to the server?**

Personally, it would be enough to install something like gnome-volume-manager, but the installation isn't successful.

```
$ root@ubuntu:/home/server# sudo apt install gnome-volume-manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gnome-volume-manager
```

Comment: To automatically mount any disk connected to your Ubuntu server on a Raspberry Pi, you can use `usbmount`. This utility is designed to automatically mount USB mass storage devices when they are plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

udev is the device manager for the Linux kernel, primarily used for dynamic device handling. You can write udev rules to automatically mount and unmount USB drives when they are connected or disconnected.

Create a Script for Mounting: First, create a script that mounts your USB drive to a designated mount point. The script can also create the mount point if it doesn't exist.

Write a udev rule to trigger this script whenever a USB device is connected. The rule would be placed in a file within /etc/udev/rules.d/.

Create Unmounting Script (Optional): Similarly, you could create a script to unmount the drive when it's disconnected.

Here is an example of a mount script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# File: /usr/local/bin/mount_usb.sh

# The device to be mounted is provided as an argument ($1)
DEVICE=$1

# Define the base mount point
MOUNT_POINT_BASE="/media/usb"

# Create a directory based on the device name
MOUNT_POINT="${MOUNT_POINT_BASE}/${DEVICE}"

mkdir -p ${MOUNT_POINT}

# Mount the device
mount /dev/${DEVICE} ${MOUNT_POINT}
```

Then write the udev Rule

Create a new file in /etc/udev/rules.d/, for example, 100-automount-usb.rules.

Add the Rule: Here’s a basic rule to trigger your script:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd?[1-9]", SUBSYSTEM=="block", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/mount_usb.sh %k"
```

This rule does the following:

- ACTION=="add": Runs the rule when a device is added.
- KERNEL=="sd?[1-9]": Applies to storage devices (like sda1, sdb2,
  etc.).
- SUBSYSTEM=="block": Restricts the rule to block devices.
- RUN+="/usr/local/bin/mount_usb.sh %k": Executes your script with the
  device name as a parameter.

Reload udev Rules:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
sudo udevadm trigger
```